# Binomial Coefficients and Function Composition

Tags: combinatorics

I found a paper that stated the following without proof. I tried to prove it on my own, but so far to no avail.

> Define $\varphi^{+}: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ by $\varphi^{+}(i,j) = i + j$.  This induces maps $\varphi^{+}_n: \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}^{n-1}$ by $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) \mapsto (\varphi^{+}(x_1,x_2), ..., \varphi^{+}(x_{n-1},x_n))$. Now let $\Phi_n: \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined as the $(n-1)$-fold composition $\Phi_n := \varphi^{+}_2 \circ ... \circ \varphi^{+}_{n-1} \circ \varphi^{+}_n$. Prove that for $n \geq 3$:
>
> $\Phi_n(a_1, ..., a_n) = a_1 + \binom{n-1}{1}a_2 + \binom{n-1}{2}a_3 + ... + \binom{n-1}{n-2}a_{n-1} + a_n = \sum^{n}_{k=1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k$

For Example $\Phi_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ gives $a_1 + 2a_2 + a_3$ and  $\Phi_4(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = a_1 +3a_2 + 3a_3 + a_4$. So there's obviously a connection to the binomial coefficients of pascal's triangle, but i don't see how the evaluation of $\Phi_n$ is related to that of $(x+y)^n$.

EDIT: Okay, here's my progress so far; as suggested by TravisJ i tried to go about this proof by induction. Note that $\varphi^{+}_2 = \varphi^{+}$.

For the base case let $n = 3$, then $\Phi_3 (a_1, a_2, a_3) = \varphi^{+}(\varphi^{+}_3(a_1, a_2, a_3)) = \varphi^{+}(a_1 + a_2, a_2 + a_3) = a_1 + 2a_2 + a_3.$

As for the induction step, we know that by the definition of the $(n-1)$-fold composition $\Phi_{n+1}(a_1, ..., a_n, a_{n+1}) = \Phi_n(\varphi^{+}_{n+1}(a_1, ..., a_n, a_{n+1})).$
Now, since $\varphi^{+}_{n+1}$ maps any $(n+1)$-tuple to a $n$-tuple by applying $\varphi^{+}$ to its components it follows from our induction hypotheses, that 
$\Phi_{n+1}(a_1, ..., a_n, a_{n+1}) = \sum^{n}_{k=1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}a'_k,$ where $a'_k = \varphi^{+}(a_k, a_{k+1}).$

I don't know where to go from there, for a short moment i even thought the proof is over. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried induction?  It seems like the natural first thing to try...

Comment: In your inductive hypothesis, it looks like you'll be adding up the previous row of the triangle, with the previous row shifted by 1 to the right... exactly what you need for Pascal's recurrence.

Comment: yes, good observation! trying this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** In order to make a proof by induction better comprehensible we will do it in *small* steps.

> Let $\varphi^{+}:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $\varphi^{+}(i,j)=i+j \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \ (1)$
>
> Let $\varphi_n^{+}:\mathbb{N}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{n-1}$ with $\varphi_n^{+}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\varphi^{+}(x_1,x_2),\ldots,\varphi^{+}(x_{n-1},x_n)\right)\qquad\quad (n\geq 2)\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)$
>
> Define $\Phi_n:=\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\cdots\circ\varphi_n^{+}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,(n\geq 2)\qquad\qquad\qquad(3)$
>
> Show that following is valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \Phi_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k\quad\qquad(n\geq 3)
> \end{align*}

We start with the

> **Base step:** $n=3$
>
> We have to show that following is valid:
>
> $\Phi_3:\mathbb{N}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $\Phi_3:=\phi_2^+\circ\phi_3^+$ fulfills
>
> \begin{align*}
> \Phi_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)&=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\binom{2}{k-1}a_k\\
> &=\binom{2}{0}a_1+\binom{2}{1}a_2+\binom{2}{2}a_3\\
> &=a_1+2a_2+a_3
> \end{align*}
>
> **Proof:**
>   \begin{align*}
> \Phi_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)&=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\right)(a_1,a_2,a_3)\tag{4}\\
> &=\varphi_2^{+}\left(\varphi_3^{+}(a_1,a_2,a_3)\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\varphi_2^{+}\left(\varphi^{+}(a_1,a_2),\varphi^{+}(a_2,a_3)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=\varphi_2^{+}(a_1+a_2,a_2+a_3)\tag{7}\\
> &=\left(\varphi^{+}(a_1+a_2,a_2+a_3)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=(a_1+a_2)+(a_2+a_3)\tag{7}\\
> &=a_1+2a_2+a_3\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use the definition of $\Phi_n$ according to (3)
- In (5) we apply the $\circ$ operator
- In (6) we use the definition of $\varphi_n^{+}$ according to (2)
- In (7) we use the definition of $\varphi^{+}$ according to (1)

> **Induction hypothesis:** $n$
>
> Let the claim be valid for $n$, so that
>
> \begin{align*}
> \Phi_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)&:=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_n^{+}\right)(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k
> \end{align*}

$$$$

> **Induction step:** $n\rightarrow n+1$
>
> Show that
>   \begin{align*}
> \Phi_{n+1}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})&:=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_{n+1}^{+}\right)(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}a_k
> \end{align*}
>
> **Proof:**
>   \begin{align*}
> \Phi_{n+1}&(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})\\
> &=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_{n}^{+}\circ\varphi_{n+1}^{+}\right)(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})\tag{4}\\
> &=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_{n}^{+}\right)\left(\varphi_{n+1}^{+}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_{n}^{+}\right)
> \left(\varphi^{+}(a_1,a_2),\varphi^{+}(a_2,a_3),\ldots,\varphi^{+}(a_n,a_{n+1})\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=\left(\varphi_2^{+}\circ\varphi_3^{+}\circ\ldots\circ\varphi_{n}^{+}\right)
> \left(a_1+a_2,a_2+a_3,\ldots,a_n+a_{n+1}\right)\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(a_k+a_{k+1})\tag{8}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_{k+1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom{n-1}{k-2}a_{k}\tag{9}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{0}a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k-2}\right)a_k+\binom{n-1}{n-1}a_{n+1}\tag{10}\\
> &=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k-1}a_k+a_{n+1}\tag{11}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}a_k\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- Steps (4) to (7): see comment above
- In (8) we do the *essential step* and apply the *induction hypothesis*
- In (9) we shift the index in the right sum by one (we want to collect terms with equal $a_k$)
- In (10) we collect the summands which occur in both sums
- In (11) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$